# Windows API MONITORINFO Structure

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to get monitor data from the windows API.
The `GetSystemMetrics()` command returns the wrong width in pixels.
According to Microsoft's website this is because I need to [`SetProcessDPIAware()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633543%28VS.85%29.aspx)

which means I should preferably be able to create an [application manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc530456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which I do not understand.

In searching for an equally low level alternative I found the [multiple display monitors functions and structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I must pass `HMONITOR` to access the rect structure I want but getting `HMONITOR` is where I am having issues.

`MonitorFromWindow(hwnd,MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY)`
This command is out of scope- strange because `GetMonitorInfo()` [which I need `HMONITOR` for] doesn't cause any issues.  I already have `windows.h` and `windowsx.h` included.  Am I missing a library or what is the issue?

On a separate note, after looking there it became evident that it might also be nice to make the monitor used user-adjustable.  `SM_CMONITORS` should return a count but I would like to know how to convert these numbers to the `HMONITOR` data I need to get monitor specific information.

::Edit::

I am putting the edit here because the "comment" feature does not provide me with enough space to place the code clip which was requested

Also, I am using GNU GCC with MinGW

```
#include <iostream>//using these libraries
#include <Windowsx.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //should print screen width in pixels

    LPMONITORINFO target;
        //create a monitor info struct to store the data to
    HMONITOR Hmon = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd,MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
        //create a handle to the main monitor
        //(should start at top left of screen with (0,0) as apposed to other monitors i believe)
        //if i could gather aditional info on what monitors are available that might be           useful
    GetMonitorInfo(Hmon, target);
        //Get the necessary data and store it to target

    cout << "bottom of selected monitor in pixels: " << target->rcMonitor.bottom
         << "Top of the selected monitor" << target->rcMonitor.top
         << "right extreme of selected monitor" << target->rcMonitor.right
         << "left extreme of selected monitor" << target->rcMonitor.left;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you give a short, complete code sample that reproduces your problems?

Comment: What compiler version you are trying to use?

Comment: Yes; thank you.  I added the additional information to the question because it would not fit in the allotted comment size.

Comment: Creating a manifest is the correct solution. What, exactly, do you not understand about manifests?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to use features that appeared after Windows 95/Windows NT 4, you must specify the WINVER before compiling.

Windows 2000 is `WINVER` `0x0500`, so the compile line needs to add `-DWINVER=0x500` in order to see the `MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY` constant.

You need to allocate a `MONITORINFO` struct, not a pointer to a `MONITORINFO` struct, and intialize the `cbSize` field so that Windows knows what information to populate, so in your code:

```
MONITORINFO target;
target.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);

HMONITOR hMon = MonitorFromWindow(GetDesktopWindow(), MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
GetMonitorInfo(hMon, &target);
```

And then display using:

```
 target.rcMonitor
```

instead of

```
target->rcMonitor
```

Using `SetProcessDPIAware()`, is a feature of Windows Vista, so `WINVER` needs to be set to `0x0600`, but the headers shipped with MinGW don't appear to be a complete set of headers for Windows Vista - That function definition is missing, but is present in the Windows 7 SDK headers (I don't have the Windows Vista SDK at hand to check it on).

So, using a manifest seems like an easier solution than pulling the newer APIs.

Monitor handles are meant to be an opaque representation of a monitor - i.e. the value you get should not be used for anything other than other monitor functions. If you want to walk the monitor structures, you should use the [`EnumDisplayMonitors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, and an appropriate callback routine.

Comment: *you must specify the WINVER before compiling* [Better yet, let `sdkddkver.h` set it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/11/2079137.aspx). It works well for targeting Vista and later.

Comment: Thanks;  because you suggest I might use an application manifest I shall attempt to learn to do so.  The first time I ever heard of one was reading through the windows API for this project so one last helpful tidbit would be a resource link.  I can't find any tutorial or information that might help me put two and two together.  Once again, thank you all; that answer was really helpful.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I was using the standalone MinGW, and it didn't contain that file. MinGW that ships with Cygwin seems to have that file, which is a much saner solution

Comment: @user1964975 a manifest file can be an embedded resource in your app, or a file that is the same name as your exe, but with the `.manifest` extension, so for example if your exe is called `foo.exe` then the manifest is called `foo.exe.manifest` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx